# Jquery and php combined?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a project that as so far has involved using php and mysql (i am new to web developing).  However i am now at the point where i would like to code an auction for my eventual website.  The obvious concern with the importance of the auctions being timed as led me onto javascript and then jquery.  I have read a bit about it but as usual it is all a bit overwhelming so i just wondered if somebody could point me in the right direction for my research.

Basically i'm bothered about how the data in mysql will be continually updated during the auction - such as current bid.  Presumably the timer somehow constantly triggers an update in my php.  So the question here i am asking is how does jquery trigger something to happen in my php?  Or can jquery update mysql itself?  Secondly where is the timer information stored.

In php i understand that when somebody visits a certain auction page the data is simply obtained using the dynamic variables and the get function.  I can do this fine.  But how would the timer know what time to show for each page (for each respective auction that is), if you understand me?  If somebody could simply outline the concepts at work i would very grateful.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please format your question properly so other can ready it easily

Comment: Yes, please use paragraphs.

Comment: this question is pretty hard to read and it's very broad. You need to ask specific questions. It doesn't seem like you've done any research

Answer (score 2):

> So the question here i am asking is how does jquery trigger something
>   to happen in my php? Or can jquery update mysql itself?

PHP is a server side language, meaning that it runs on the web server, gets parsed and the code executes and the resulting HTML code is sent to the client.

Javascript (and hence jQuery) runs on the client, which is the browser. The client actions cannot actually perform any server actions, one being accessing mySql databases.

What you would do is send data to your PHP script which would then save it to the database.

> But how would the timer know what time to show for each page (for each
>   respective auction that is)

Basically you need to work with a good approximation of time. If you know what time the auction ends and you know what time it is now, then you can calculate how much time is left and using javascript/jquery you can display the time left.

What you might need is a quick way to communicate back and forth from the server to the client. A technology called [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp), and it can do [precisely that](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is handled clientside, lets say someone is viewing your website and viewing a product, at a sudden that product was overbidded, a good and a bad solution to this would be to use ajax requests which is very trivial using Jquery.

You can then get the information from lets say itembid.php?id=429, and get the current bid for the item id.

Lets say you have a timer on the webpage aswell(javascript) that checks this then every client would automatically get an request to see if the item is overbidded every x second.

Hope i understood you right.

This might be helpful.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/